# Result of deleting object from hibernate database

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm curious what should be result when I create object, Then I delete object and then I try to load this object from database. I guess it should be "null". In one table I receive "null" in second table i receive nothing.

Create:

```
public void createPerson(Person p) {
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(p);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    logger.info("Person saved successfully!");
}
```

Delete:

```
public void deletePerson(int id) {
    session.beginTransaction();

    Person p = getPersonById(id);
    if(p != null){
        session.delete(p);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    if(getPersonById(id) == null){
    logger.info("Person deleted successfully!");
    }else{
        logger.info("Something went wrong! Person hasn't been deleted!");           
    }

}
```

and load:

```
public Person getPersonById(int id) {
    session.beginTransaction();
    Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, id);
    logger.info("Person loaded successfully!");
    return p;

}
```

And I receive nothing. What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `nothing`?

Comment: Exactely nothing. I don't know how to describe it. I just don't see anything. It doesn't give me any value, object, whatever. When I try to System.out.print it, it doesn't write anything. Even when I try do System.out.print("blabla"+result); -> I cant find even the "blabla" sentence in log. :D Its completely weird.

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception caught? Have you check your program on a debugger? This `nothing` thing does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you should flush your context after create/delete operation.The flush process synchronizes database state with session state by detecting state changes and executing SQL statements.

```
if(p != null){
        session.delete(p);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
session.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    }
```

You can read about flush mode [Hibernate flush mode.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Where is the commit in `deletePerson`? and the commit again in `getPersonById`?

Fix the code you would see that you don't get the entity back by ID one you delete it.

Comment: Commit in deletePerson is on the line 7. And I thought commit is important only when I change something so it doesn't have to be in getPersonById. However I put it there and it didn't change anything.

Comment: put try catch everywhere and print the trace to see if anything goes wrong. also once you delete check the DB is the record deletes actually